# Help anti-transforming this partial DE using Laplace transform.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I'm trying to solve $$\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}\ (x > 0,\ t > 0)\\
u(0,t)=1,\ u(x,0)=0
\end{cases}$$

I've transformed this to $$ sU - u(x,0) = \frac{d^2U}{dx^2} \to sU = \frac{d^2U}{dx^2} $$ But I don't know how could I anti-transform the resulting DE:

$$ U = A\exp(\sqrt{s}x) + B\exp(-\sqrt{s}x) $$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

A slightly more general problem is
$$\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t} = k \, \dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} \hspace{5mm} (x > 0,\ t > 0)\\
u(0,t) = u_{0},\ u(x,0)=0.
\end{cases}$$
Using the Laplace transform on the variable $t$ leads to
$$ \bar{u}'' - \frac{s}{k} \, \bar{u} = 0 \hspace{5mm} \bar{u}(0, s) = \frac{u_{0}}{s}, \bar{u}(x,0)=0$$
and
$$ \bar{u}(x, s) = A \, e^{\sqrt{s/k} \, x} + B \, e^{- \sqrt{s/k} \, x}.$$
The solution must be bounded as $x \to \infty$ which implies $A=0$. Applying the conditions yields
$$ \bar{u}(x, s) = \frac{u_{0}}{s} \, e^{- \sqrt{s/k} \, x}. $$
Without proof of the inverse Laplace transform the solution is given by
$$ u(x, t) = u_{0} \, \text{erfc}\left( \frac{x}{2 \, \sqrt{k \, t}}\right).$$